# A word to describe an unexpected advancement in someone's learning progress

Tags: single-word-requests

How to describe an unexpected or surprising advancement in someone's learning progress?

For example, in one teacher's class there are some students who were quite lazy in the first semester, but suddenly became extremely enthusiastic in the middle of the second semester. However, this sudden change did not happen with all the students. So, say, Jack is one of such "no-sudden-change" students. However, Jack was not at all a bad student. So, the teacher is writing in Jack's progress report in the end of the second semester:

> Although Jack hasn't shown any surprising **upsurge** in his learning
>   progress as was the case with quite a few other students in this class during this semester, he has nevertheless been quite diligent
>   and active.

I guess the word "upsurge" wouldn't fit in here as, as I perceive, it is usually used in reference to many people (like "upsurge in sales"), rather than to one person.

"Advancement" would probably not work here either as advancement, as far as I understand, implies a more steady process rather than a sudden one.

So, what word would fit in here then?

Comment: Hasn’t made any dramatic leaps...

Comment: If the student has not shown any significant progress, a teacher will write  in his report: "Jack has made steady progress" leaving out the "surprising" bit, because there is no surprise. Reports are individual not collective, but maybe this is different in your country. I would; however, rephrase your sample sentence to:  "*Jack has shown **a surprising** *upsurge in his learning during this semester and he has also been diligent and active.*"

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I meant to make the teacher slightly compare Jack to other students. Please, see my edit that I made just now in the teacher's words.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - So, would you still use the word "upsurge" even though the the reports are individual?

Comment: It's better now, but I still wouldn't compare Jack's progress with the rest of the class in a school report that is addressed to his parents. I'd only focus on the student's progress; strengths and weaknesses.  But  the sample sentence is clearer, so I suppose I had better shut up. :) EDIT: The term *upsurge* is NOT idiomatic in this situation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I see. Thank you. "**The term upsurge is NOT idiomatic in this situation**" - What does this mean? Does it mean that the word "upsurge" will not cause any other (wrong) meanings? Can you, please, elaborate.

Comment: And this is where I stop commenting because you are placing in bold (unnecessarily) my comments. We've already had an exchange in the past, and I see what you're doing here. I am not going to get myself in a squabble with you. The comment is clear, *upsurge* is not idiomatic to describe a student's **vast improvement** (i.e. the situation)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - What squabble do you mean???

Comment: In the past, you don't remember great. But I do. End of.

Comment: Jack continues to meet expectations in his learning progress.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Well, sorry to see you go. If you could bring up to my memories a few details of that "squabble", then I would probably recall.  But at the moment I am quite "blank". I don't understand what's wrong with quoting your words in bold. I do this all the time to make clear what point I am addressing and no one gets offended because of that (and I would definitely not be offended by that).

Comment: @Jim - You have already given me two great word choices. Why wouldn't you do this as an answer instead of a comment? In this case I would make it as a best answer and you would get some points.

Comment: You could also use "advances in learning". Though it's not exactly BE, I have mostly seen the use of "advances" in text from British writers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... Jack hasn't shown any **unexpected breakthrough** in his learning progress ...
Or, 
... Jack's progress hasn't made an **unusually significant advance** in his learning progress as was the case ...
Or, more formally, 
... Jack hasn't achieved the **notable large increase** in his learning progress ...

Comment: I like "breakthrough" as it feels the most idiomatic to steps in learning.  (light-bulbs go on etc)

Answer (score 2):

One way to describe it would be by using "improving **by leaps and bounds**".

> [**By leaps and bounds**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by-leaps-and-bounds) (link to Collins dictionary)
>
> ```
>   with unexpectedly rapid progess
> ```
>
> E.g. "her condition improved by leaps and bounds"

Answer (score 0):

There has not been a **quantum leap** in his attainment.

> quantum leap
>
> a ... sudden increase, or dramatic advance

[[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quantum%20leap)]

Comment: Wiktionary defines "quantum leap" as an "abrupt, extreme change". It does not specify that the change is _positive_.

Comment: @Flater I thought you recognised the authority of [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quantum+leap)?

Comment: Fair enough. I based myself on the top Google result for "quantum leap", ignoring the TV show and results pertaining to physics. it's not that I recognize a specific authority (Collins or other), it's that I believe language is a matter of societal agreement and usage. By that principle, the definition on the most referenced page would be the most correct.

Comment: It seems attractive, and over-prescriptiveness is senseless. But if one adopts the 'the majority must be right' policy wholesale, one is left abandoning one's national treasures to millions of English learners in more populous foreign countries. I don't think site policy here is to grant Wiktionary 'most authoritative' status. It has far less rigorous editorial standards than say Collins, AHD, OED [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiktionary)]

Comment: It's an open discussion. Established rigorous standards can stand in the way of innovation, and a language should evolve over time (who wants to speak Old English nowadays?). Not without merit in some cases, but definitely not all cases.

Comment: Wiktionary will apparently allow a candidate word to be listed if there are three apparently independent examples in print, online.... OED get the reference books, microfiches etc out for every candidate, and use a usage panel of experts.

Comment: But as it usually goes, the deeper an expert digs into the "observable truth" of the topic, the more he is disconnected from the point of view of the vast majority of casual users. This is similar to politicians who influence common law (e.g. taxes and economy), but have at times shown to not even know the average cost of everyday groceries. This does not automatically debunk the expert's opinion, but it does put an asterisk next to the relevance of their expert opinion.

Comment: @nohat diagnoses the problem with Wiktionary in a discussion here on [Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/484/common-accepted-online-resources): 'Wiktionary can also have good data but it should be taken with a grain of salt. Their lexicographic methods are inconsistent: some of it is as good as any other dictionary. Sometimes it harbors undisclosed biases, and sometimes it is just amateurish.' I've not heard OED being described this way.

Comment: We're arguing different points. I consider correct language from popularity in usage, and apply the same principle to source preference. You are arguing correctness based on past merit or established methodology (both rely on meeting a necessary standard to be considered viable). I'm not saying either of us is more correct than the other, but apples and oranges.

Comment: I'm saying that ELU isn't a free-for-all. There seem to be websites that are.

Answer (score 0):

While I strongly support Edwin's "quantum leap", I will offer another possibility you could consider.  First, I will caution you not to share the paragraph you included in your question with anyone.  This type of comparison will not earn you any respect if expressed blatantly in this way.  So I will assume that this is an artificially constructed context paragraph, made just for the purpose of getting your idea across here.

> Although Jack hasn't shown any ***big swings*** in his learning progress [<strike>as was the case with quite a few other students in this class during this semester</strike>], he has nevertheless been quite diligent and active [*and his steady progress has been gratifying to see*].

***swing*** (noun)

> a change: *He experiences severe *mood swings* (= sudden changes from one extreme mood to another); the party only needs a five percent *swing* (= needs five percent of voters to change to supporting it) to win this election.* ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swing))

Comment: Very interesting! And very good suggestions. Thank you!